# Cordova LocalStorage doesn't work

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

Do I have to install a plugin in Android platform? I cannot find anything for a plugin in the Cordova documentation.

```
function save(){
    window.localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
    var keyname = window.localStorage.key(i);
    var value = window.localStorage.getItem("key");
    alert (value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dario, since you are using `LocalStorage` there is no plugin required. I am not sure about your statement:

`window.localStorage.key(i);`

Where is `i` set?

I have a UTIL class I use with Getter / Setter. Here is the `js` for that. Hope this helps.

```
var util = function () {
    return {    
        //-----------------------------------
        set: function (key, value) {
            localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
        },
        //-----------------------------------
        get: function (key, defaultVal) {
            var value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
            if (value === null) value = defaultVal;
            return value;
        },
  }; //End Return

}(); //End Closure


//Sample Set
util.set("downloadFlag", 1);

//Sample Get (with a default value 0 if null is found)
var fileDownloadedFlag = util.get("downloadFlag", 0);
```